# Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to run Spyder in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm setting up a separate environment to work in. However, whenever I try running spyder, I receive this error:

```
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pythonw: line 3: 84700 Segmentation fault: 11 /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

I have no idea what this means. The commands I used to get to this point were:

```
conda create -n myenv python
conda activate myenv
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install -c conda-forge spyder
spyder
```

I have anaconda navigator installed, and spyder runs fine in the root environment. I do receive the statement "link image0 hasn't been detected!" every time I run it.

I've always used spyder and anaconda, and I've never had these issues before

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same problem for several weeks and spent many days trying to fix it. Of the countless operations I attempted, I finally got spyder to successfully run from its own conda environment without throwing the segmentation fault error you've referenced.

With a fresh install of anaconda3 on macOS 10.14.6, I created a conda environment from the command line just as you’ve shown:

`conda create -n myenv python`
`conda activate myenv`

*A comment about:*

> conda create -n myenv python

*Note 1: if you list* “`spyder`” *to install during the environment creation there’s no need to include* “`python`” *as a package unless you wish to have a specific version. For example,* “`python=2.7.9`”*, or* “`python=3.10.*`”*. Otherwise, python gets added automatically when the environment is created.*

Next,

> conda config --add channels conda-forge

instead of setting the conda configuration to use the conda-forge channel and instead of including it as a channel when installing spyder into your conda environment, simply install spyder using the virgin (unmodified) default channel configuration by only typing:

`conda install spyder`

Now when you run `spyder` from the command line within your active environment it should open as expected.

As previously indicated, you can install spyder during the environment creation:
`conda create -n myenv spyder`

Then you can activate the environment to test everything:
`conda activate myenv`
`spyder`

*Note 2: the official [spyder documentation](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html) recommends including the* `-c conda-forge` *channel, but this was the entry that I removed to finally avoid the segmentation fault. I suspect that although the community repository at conda-forge keeps the most up-to-date versions, there are conflicts not being resolved at creation of the new local environment.*

Furthermore, you may notice that the method described above installs spyder version 5.3.3 and spyder-kernels version 2.3.3, both of which are not the most up-to-date. You could check this by running `conda list` from the command line and then searching for the corresponding entries.

However, if you try to update spyder by calling `conda update spyder`, the system will tell you that all packages are currently installed. This is because the virgin channel defaults are looking at the anaconda repository, not conda-forge. My suggestion for right now is **not** to attempt updating spyder in your conda environment because it will update other packages as dependencies that will result in breaking the application again.

In case you’re curious, to get the most recent version of spyder based on the procedure I've described above would be by setting the channel as follows: `conda update spyder -c conda-forge`. Depending on your OS, this will install spyder 5.4.1 and spyder-kernels 2.4.1 (as of 16-Jan-23), but it will also remove and update several other packages, hence causing compatibility issues.

**UPDATE:**
My key takeaway is to remove the `-c conda-forge` from the installation line of code to prevent the segmentation fault when using *conda*. Everything else is up to the user. Installing with pip, brew, or any other method is discretionary but could also result in more trouble than it’s worth for the already frustrated user.

If you run `conda create -n myenv spyder` at the environment creation or `conda install spyder` after creating the environment, the packages pyqt and qtpy are installed alongside spyder because they are dependencies and not explicitly needed (unless specifying specific versions). If you run `pip install spyder`, the packages pyqt5 and qtpy get installed. (as of 16-Jan-23)

**Caution:**
*(with reservation because if you can follow instructions and you are both okay with and the only one affected by the consequences of your choices when things go wrong, I support you to thoughtfully experiment and explore if you so desire)*

According to the docs, using pip to install packages within the conda environment is reserved for experienced users. A big reason for this caution is because pip and conda don’t communicate and so package versions and dependencies can become incompatible if the user is not aware of what’s happening. It should also be pointed out that if and when using pip, one should generally install all the desired conda packages prior to installing a package with pip. Problems usually present themselves when updating, or installing with conda after pip. When this becomes necessary the general advice is to start over and install new packages as well as updated versions in a new environment.

*Installing with brew is unsupported by the spyder devs. This can be referenced from the spyder documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

I created a new conda environment with:

```
conda create --name uquant python=3.11
```

Then,

```
conda activate uquant
```

```
conda install spyder=5.4.3
```

With this I am able to start spyder